# Batch .txt processing with multiple columns

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file, cmd

I have a little problem, I would like to edit data with the following batch script.

```
@echo off

set "txt=C:\Users\Desktop\test-batch\input.txt"
set "temp=C:\Users\Desktop\test-batch\output.txt"

for /f "tokens=1-43 delims=; " %%a in (%txt%) do echo %%a;%%ac;%%ad;%%ae;%%af;%%ag;%%ah;%%ai;%%aj;%%ak;%%al;%%am;%%an;%%ao;%%ap;%%aq; > %temp%
```

input.txt:

```
1;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;1;;;1-Trackingnummer;2-Trackingnummer;3-Trackingnummer;4-Trackingnummer;5-Trackingnummer;6-Trackingnummer;7-Trackingnummer;8-Trackingnummer;9-Trackingnummer;10-Trackingnummer;11-Trackingnummer;12-Trackingnummer;13-Trackingnummer;14-Trackingnummer;15-Trackingnummer;
```

output.txt *(column `1` and columns `29-43`)*:

```
1;1-Trackingnummer;2-Trackingnummer;3-Trackingnummer;4-Trackingnummer;5-Trackingnummer;6-Trackingnummer;7-Trackingnummer;8-Trackingnummer;9-Trackingnummer;10-Trackingnummer;11-Trackingnummer;12-Trackingnummer;13-Trackingnummer;14-Trackingnummer;15-Trackingnummer;
```

Can someone tell me where the problem is and why it doesn't work?

Comment: Hi, you should at least tell us what is the goal of this batch, what do you want in output and what is the input in order to understand what should be the correct behaviour and be able to help you.

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help text; you'll find out that there is no `%%aa`, `%%ab`, etc. To get more tokens, nest two `for /F` loops, like this: `for /F "usebackq tokens=1-25* delims=;" %%A in ("%txt%") do for /F "tokens=1-18 delims=;" %%a in ("%%Z") do echo %%A...%%Y; %%a...%%r`. Alternatively, change the `tokens` option to skip tokens that you are not using: `for /F "usebackq tokens=1,29* delims=;" %%A in ("%txt%") do echo %%A;%%B;%%C`. Anyway, regard that consecutive delimiters are collapsed to a single one!

Comment: I strongly sugest you to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62018681/edit) and include the output _you want_! **`:(`**

Comment: Thanks, that works: for /F "usebackq tokens=1-25* delims=;" %%A in ("%txt%") do for /F "tokens=1-18 delims=;" %%a in ("%%Z") do echo %%A;%%M;%%N;%%O;%%P;%%Q;%%R;%%S;%%T;%%U;%%V;%%W;%%X;%%Y;%%a;%%b; > %temp%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What follows is a potential solution which doesn't use `tokens` and `delimiters` in the same way as your `for /f` loop. The idea of this is to output tokens `1` and `29-43` of your `semicolon` delimited lines, *(as per your example)*.

Please don't forget to correct the file paths in lines `2` and `3` before testing it.

```batch-file
@Echo Off&SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "source=C:\Users\Desktop\test-batch\input.txt"
Set "target=C:\Users\Desktop\test-batch\output.txt"

If Exist "%source%" (For %%G In ("%source%")Do If "%%~aG" GEq "d" GoTo :EOF)Else GoTo :EOF
For %%G In ("%target%\..")Do If "%%~aG" Lss "d" GoTo :EOF

For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('Set f[ 2^>NUL')Do Set "%%G="

(For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type "%source%"')Do Call :Sub "%%G") 1> "%target%"
GoTo :EOF

:Sub
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If "%~1" == "" Exit /B
Set "line=%~1"
Set "i=1"
Set "f[!i!]=%line:;="&Set /A i+=1&Set "f[!i!]=%"
Set "out=!f[1]!;"
For /L %%I In (29,1,43)Do Set "out=!out!!f[%%I]!;" 
Echo(%out%
EndLocal
Exit /B
```

Line `5` and `6` are just checks that your source and target are valid. If the source is not an existing file, or target file directory does not exist, the script is closed.

Line `8` ensures that we have no pre-defined variables with names beginning with `f[`.

Line `10` reads from the source file and passes each line to the `:Sub` label which performs the token parsing.

The code in the `:Sub` label splits each token using the delimiter, setting each to an independent variable, *(`f[#]`, where `#` is the token number)*. The required variables are then joined in a holding variable, *(`%out%`)*, which is finally `echo`ed to `%target%`.

In your case the majority of your tokens were a complete range, so I was able to propagate `%out%` with token `1`, *(line `19`)*, and all of the range `29..45` on line `20`. If your tokens change then you may replace lines `19` and `20` to `Set "out="`, and e.g. `For %%I In (1 29 32 34 35 37 39 43)Do Set "out=!out!!f[%%I]!;"` respectively.

*Please note that this idea was written to be able to perform the task you laid out in your question. It has a line character length limit and the number of tokens is limited to the allowed size of the environment.*