# Batch script does not work with fewer records but why?

Tags: batch-file

Good day,

I have different input files with different content. But always the same number of columns.

The structure is as follows:

```
ABC1234567890;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1.75;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;;;
```

Now I have the following batch script:

```
@echo off

set "txt=C:\Users\test-batch\input.csv"
set "temp=C:\Users\test-batch\output.csv"

for /F "usebackq tokens=1-25* delims=;" %%A in ("%txt%") do for /F "tokens=1-18 delims=;" %%a in ("%%Z") do echo %%A;Yes;%%M;%%N;%%O;%%P;%%Q;%%R;%%S;%%T;%%U;%%V;%%W;%%X;%%Y;%%a;%%b; > %temp%
```

The output file should have the following content:

```
ABC1234567890;Yes;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;123456789;;;
```

Here I would like to copy the first column + 29 - 43 column into a new file.

Now I have the problem, as soon as more than 2 columns in columns 29 - 43 are not filled, it unfortunately no longer works.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: What is wrong with using [the code which does exactly what you want](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62024957), to the same requirements, which I provided , and you accepted, in [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62018681)? As a side note, I very much doubt that you're going to get a second field in your record with `yes` in it, because it didn't exist anywhere on the line in `input.txt`. As for your issue, multiple adjacent delimiters are counted as one. And once again, the answer I gave you previously does not have that limitation, and will still provide the output you require!

Comment: The main problem is that `for` loops do not recognize (or tokenize) _empty_ strings i.e. if `delims=;` then e.g. in `1.75;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;123456789` are recognized only three tokens. See e.g. `for /F "tokens=1-25* delims=;" %A in ("1.75;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;3;;;123456789") do @echo %A %B %C` which returns `1.75 3 123456789`.